# Why do I have to set the error state flag to goodbit in order for this to work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream os("test.txt");
    std::ifstream is("test.txt");
    std::string value("0");

    os << "Hello";
    is >> value;

    std::cout << "Result before tie(): \"" << value << "\"\n";
    is.clear();
    is.tie(&os);

    is >> value;

    std::cout << "Result after tie(): \"" << value << "\"\n";
}
```

The above code has the output:

```
Result before tie(): "0"
Result after tie(): "Hello"
```

But without the `clear()` call, `value` stays "0" - why? Why do I have to set the error state flag of the input stream to goodbit?

Note that the file cannot be found, which is the intention.

Comment: What is your intention in tie() ing the streams?

Comment: To demonstrate what tie does - I am playing around with the tie function :)

Comment: I assume you mean 'But **without** the `clear()` call, `value` stays "0"'

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that you hit the end-of-file when you read `value` from `is`. And apparently the flag doesn't get cleared by `tie()`ing the output stream.

If the EOF flag remains set, no additional character will be read from the stream, so trying to read a new value for `value` will fail.

Comment: But still, why does clearing the flag let `value` change?

Comment: @FacPam: That's just how it works. You can't read anything from a stream after hitting the "end-of-file".